Creating mask for shapes based on color in image python
I would like to extract some shapes and create mask based on shape colours from this image

(the mask should be created for the red shapes) and below the expected figure

then I want to determine the area of these shapes.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from colorthief import ColorThief

ct=ColorThief('image_red.png')
domainant_color = ct.get_color(quality=1)
palette = ct.get_palette(color_count=number_colors)
print(palette)
plt.imshow([[palette[i] for i in range(number_colors)]])
plt.show()

#LOAD IMAGE 
image_org=cv2.imread("image_red.png",0)
print(image_org.shape)

#FILTER /REMOVE NOISES
img_filter=cv2.medianBlur(image_org, 3)

#### THRESHOLDING..
thresh_value,thresh_img=cv2.threshold(img_filter,0,225,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
low=np.array([251, 4, 4], dtype = "uint8") #this is based on values from palette 
upper=np.array([251, 4, 4], dtype = "uint8")#this is based on values from palette 
img_f = cv2.cvtColor(thresh_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask1=cv2.inRange(img_f,lo,up)
io.imshow(mask1)
plt.show()

I started via the following steps:

getting palette of most 5 dominant colors, then getting RGB of red color
importing original image. Then I used filter to remove noises and then thresholding(but not sure if the thresholding is correct or not ).
I applied cv2.Range and added lower and upper values of RGB of red to only get red shapes and create mask...

The result seems to give me the other phases, not the red color shapes. What can I do to get only the red shapes as I attached expected image file?

Why are you even bothering with ColorThief? Just convert to HSV/HSL and threshold the saturation channel to find coloured areas.

@MarkSetchell
Thanks for your comment, I am not sure if I understood well, may I kindly ask you to write down some lines in the code ? as I am new to image analysis and not sure if I understand what you said ??

You need to convert your image to HSV and then you can filter any shade of any color. Check this post it's answers explains everything about "Color Filtering": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv

follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79179613/specific-contour-detection-based-on-color-in-python

Unless your question is misleading, you are simply looking for coloured pixels. These are most readily found by converting to HSV colourspace and looking for pixels with high saturation, since black, white and grey pixels will all have zero saturation.
The code will look like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# Load image and convert to HSV colourspace
im = cv.imread('YOURIMAGE.jpg')
HSV = cv.cvtColor(im,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Select the Saturation channel
S = HSV[:,:,1]

# Save Saturation channel for debug purposes
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-sat.png', S)

# Decide some threshold
# Save thresholded Saturation channel for debug purposes
thr = S>50
cv.imwrite('DEBUG_thr.png', thr*255)

# Count the saturated pixels and total image area
Nsat = np.count_nonzero(thr)
area = im.shape[0]*im.shape[1]

# Output results
print(f'{Nsat=}, {area=}')

That prints:
Nsat=6774, area=436230

And the intermediate, debug image looks like this:


If you want to detect the black pixels, you will want those with low Saturation (i.e. not colourful) and low value (i.e. not bright):
# Mask of black pixels: Any Hue, Low Saturation, Low value
lo = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
hi = np.array([255, 50, 30], np.uint8)
blackMask = cv.inRange(HSV, lo, hi)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-black.png', blackMask)


If you want to detect the light grey pixels, you will want those with low Saturation (i.e. not colourful) and medium value (i.e. neither bright white nor dark black):
# Mask of light grey pixels: Any Hue, Low Saturation, Medium High value
lo = np.array([0, 0, 120], np.uint8)
hi = np.array([255, 50, 200], np.uint8)
greyMask = cv.inRange(HSV, lo, hi)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-grey.png', greyMask)



Thank you so much for your answer and suggestion,
Sounds working, but in case I need also to create mask for black bubbles or gray, how to select the Saturation channel ? or upper and lower limits of HSV, when earlier I applied color thief was trying to detect colors HSV ?
So any suggestion ?
Thanks,

If you want to detect the black pixels, you would choose those with low Saturation (i.e. not coloured) and low Value (i.e. not bright). If you want to detect grey pixels, you would choose those with low Saturation (i.e. not coloured) and medium Value (i.e. not low because that would be black and not high because that would be white). A simple mask is in the answer already thr = S>50. This answer shows how to make masks and combine them with AND and OR operations https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019059/2836621

Thanks again, but I still can not get the point of how to get the HSV color range or saturation from the image then apply it to create mask ?
For example, how would you do the same if you wanna only create mask for black bubbles or dark grey bubbles ?

I've added some more examples, so you can see how to select pixels where each of the Hue, Saturation and Value are in a desired range.

Thanks for your kind explanation, I totally understand, but my question is how would I know low and upper values ?, that's why at the beginning I used colortheif, as for me.. it would be helpful to detect color ranges then apply it .. So my question is there a way to detect upper and lower limits HSV from image first ?
Also, why when you tried to get. mask for grey, it includes red bubbles  as well, it should be without red or black bubbles ?

You can use OpenCV trackbars for HSV or RGB ranges. Search this forum for trackbars. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480131/python-opencv-hsv-range-finder-creating-trackbars
